# How to create a form in react native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-native

I am creating a registration form in React Native. Currently, I am using `useState()` hook for each field:

```
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState("");
  const [userPassword, setUserPassword] = useState("");
```

This way does the job, but is it the correct one? Is it possible to manage it by using a single `useState()` instead of having state one for each field? Should I use package [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) or another package?

Edit:

```
  const [registerForm, setRegisterForm] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    userEmail: "",
    userPassword: ""
  });
```

This way would also work.

Comment: You should definetly keep the state separated - mergin the states together would not be best praxis.

Comment: Why is not a best practice? Do you have any reference?

Comment: Try also checking out Formik

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks!